# a href to chrome:// url in a chrome extension how to make it work

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've written a Chrome extension to use as an iframe in my own locally stored home page. I just want a way to access the basic settings, extensions, bookmarks, and so forth. I know this is denied in a standard html. I thought an api should do the trick:

```
onclick="chrome.tabs.create({url:'chrome://settings'});"
```

but to no avail. How can I access these settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access chrome pages from an extension. However you could get some settings with [Chrome APIs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html)

Specifically [Bookmarks API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html), [Installed extensions API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html)